# python reverse phone lookup with twilio

Tags: python-2.7, twilio

I've been looking for a way to do reverse phone lookups with python. I know there are other ways but it would be great if I could do it in python. The module I'm using is twilio which I'm not sure is the best method. If there's a better way can someone tell me? Anyways, what I have so far only tells me a phone number's carrier, I'm trying to get more specific information like names, emails, addresses, ip addresses, locations, and any personal info. If someone could help me with this little project that would be great:)

What I have so far:

```
import sys
import os
from twilio.rest.lookups import TwilioLookupsClient

try:
    client = TwilioLookupsClient()
    phone = raw_input (" Enter The Targets Phone Number: ")

    number = client.phone_numbers.get((phone), include_carrier_info=True, )
    print(number.carrier['name'])
    print(number.carrier['type'])
except:
    print ("Error handling phone number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you're looking for even more data on top of what Twilio itself provides then you probably should take a look at our [Add-on marketplace](https://www.twilio.com/marketplace/add-ons).

We have add-ons for the [Lookups API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups), including the following which should help with your specific situation:

#### [Whitepages Pro Caller Identification](https://www.twilio.com/marketplace/add-ons/whitepages-pro-caller-id)

> Whitepages Pro Caller Identification helps you identify an unknown caller's name, their demographics, including age range and gender, and address. It also provides phone details, including line-type, carrier, and pre-paid status.

#### [Advanced Caller ID by Next Caller](https://www.twilio.com/marketplace/add-ons/nextcaller-advanced-caller-id)

> Next Caller can identify +600M phone numbers with the following data points: Name, Address, Email, Carrier, Line Type, Secondary Phone, Age, Gender, Household Income, Marital Status, Presence of Children, Home Owner Status, Home Market Value, Length of Residence, High Net Worth, Occupation, Education Level, Twitter Handle & Followers, Facebook Profile & Followers, LinkedIn Profile

Both of these APIs can be added as part of the Lookups API so you can gather all the information you're after.

Let me know if that helps at all.

**Edit:**

Here's an example of calling the API using the Whitepages Pro Add-on from above. This is using the Twilio Python library, version 6.4.3.

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

number = client.lookups.phone_numbers("+15108675309").fetch(type="carrier", add_ons="whitepages_pro_caller_id")

print(number.add_ons)
```

`number.add_ons` is a dict of the results from any add on you include. It's probably best to just inspect it to see what data you want to extract.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I don't want to be one of those people who asks for the code but I'm kind of lost while trying to make the program:/

Comment: I got this error "Requirements to invoke AddOns have not been me" (code: 61003)

Comment: @matt Did you check the error description? Any of the ideas here help: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/61003

Comment: @philnash Requirements to invoke AddOns have not been met

Comment: @matt It might be better to ask a new question including the code that you are using that is getting this response. Let me know when you've asked it and I'll try to answer from the information you provide.